# How much memory will my columnstore indexes need?

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2014, columnstore

I would like to add clustered columnstore indexes to some tables in a SQL Server 2014 database. Before doing so, I need to gather a good estimate of required memory.  How can I predict clustered columnstore memory usage?

Things I know:

- The size of the tables on disk
- How the tables will be queried
- The growth rate of these tables on disk

Comment: So did you answer your own question? or you are still looking for it!!

Comment: Still looking for it.  I know the size of the rowstore table on disk but not what that will translate to in memory if I create a columnstore index

Answer (score 0):

You will find an answer here - [source](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/126202/) - under the title "Memory Usage".

I'd rather not copy & paste the relevant section as the Terms Of Use of sqlservercentral.com state "You are not permitted to copy or use any of the Redgate Materials for any purpose." Though presumably the Terms Of Use themselves are exempt from this condition. :-)

Comment: Nice, so [(4.2 * IC) + 68] * T + (ISC * 34) gives usage in megabytes, where IC = Number of Indexed Columns, ISC = Number of Indexed String Columns, and T = Number of Threads.

Comment: That's right. I found it enlightening that the volume of rows does not impact on memory required, as it only processes them one "chunk" of rows at a time (up to a million rows).